# How can I use ⨝ and ⊐ in my LaTeX document?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to insert some symbols from [LaTeX Math Symbols](http://web.ift.uib.no/Fysisk/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) into my LaTeX document: under the relational symbols heading, I want join (⨝) and square supset (⊐).

They both have a little b symbol after them.  What does that mean; how do I insert them into my doc?  I tried adding them ignoring the b but it seemed to error and not work.

I'm using the small Mac install of LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're using meta-LaTeX on you: that is a superscript "b" ($ indicates a short math expression and the caret is the superscript).

What they're indicating is that there is a footnote.  It is shown in the "Binary Operation Symbols" section.

> $^b$ Not predefined in a format based
>   on {\tt basefont.tex}.
>        Use one of the style options 
>        {\tt oldlfont}, {\tt newlfont}, {\tt amsfonts} or {\tt amssymb}.

So, if you are seeing an error, that would indicate to me that you are using a basefont format.  Try one of the style options listed in the footnote and see if you have more luck.  As explained below,

> \usepackage{newlfont}

is worth a try.  That should enable symbols such as `\Join`.

Answer (score 7):

My copy of *A Guide to LaTeX* by Helmut and Kopka says of `\sqsupset` (amongst others):

"Note: the underlined symbol names [...] are only available in LaTeX 2e if one of the packages `latexsym` or `amsfonts` has been loaded."

The book doesn't show `\Join` in its symbol tables at all, however it lists `\bowtie` which appears to produce the same symbol, and which has no footnotes or warnings associated with it at all :-)

Answer (score 3):

As the footnote on that page explaines, you should use special settings to get these symbols. So for instance, if you add `\usepackage{newlfont}` to the top of your file, you'll be able to get the symbols, e.g. `$\sqsubset$`.